# Finding Table Within Table - JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to find, using JQuery, the row and column number of a table cell.  However, my tables are nested:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table><tr><TD></TD></tr></table>
        <td>
            <table>...</table>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    ...
</table>
```

The td object that JQuery should act on is the on on the inner table.  I have noted it with capitals in the above code.

I've seen some examples for single tables - is there a way to do this for nested ones as well?

EDIT:

That is to say, I am trying to find the row and column number of the OUTSIDE table, but the object being acted on is an INSIDE td element.

Comment: can't you add an id to those tables? it would be so much easier and cleaner to maintain later

Comment: To retrieve the inner tables use $("table table"). Please clarify what you mean about row and column of OUTER table.

Comment: XepterX - The tables are fairly ambiguous... if I gave them ID's relating them to their row/column (eg. innerTable1-2), I may as well just access them by their row and column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you the parent `td`:

```
$('#inner-td').parent().closest('td');
```

**Note:** using just `parent()` will not work, since that only looks at the immediate parent. Using `closest()` on its own wouldn't work either, since it'll return the current `td`, because `closest()` looks for the closest element matching the passed selector, [*including the current element*](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Answer (score 2):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pg4sj/

Code:

```
$('table table td').click(function() { // change this to suit your selector
    var theTD = $(this).parents('table:first').parents('td:first');
    var col = theTD.index() + 1;
    var row = theTD.parents('tr:first').index() + 1;
    alert('[Row, Col] => ['+row+', '+col+']');
});
```